# change div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

With pure Javascript I want to create a tab effect to toggle content in a div. **Content** is the name of the class I want to add or remove the second class **active** from

```
            <script>
            function changeClass(element) {

                if (classList !=='active') {
                    element.classList.add('active');
                }
                else { element.classList.remove('active'); }
            }
            </script>
            <ul>
                <li onclick = "changeClass("content")">
```

Comment: why don't you try this with jquery?

Comment: Please see how to use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

Comment: I agree with @shijin... jQuery would be much easier in this instance.

Comment: classList isn't available in IE 9.  http://caniuse.com/classlist

Comment: To all the jQuery guys: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: @Teemu Please write it as an answer before jQuery takes over.

Comment: @PatrickAllen But we also weren't talking about using a fat framework for one line of code... Not the best programming attitude.

Comment: It was just a mere suggestion.  I never said he shouldn't use vanilla JS. I'm not a proponent of one or the other.  I'll make sure to leave my ideas out next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you're not selecting any elements (wonder why nobody caught this), but trying to change the classlist of a string (`"content".classList...`). Make sure you select the proper element first:

```
function changeClass(element) {
    element = document.getElementsByClassName(element)[0]; // assuming here we're selecting the first one
    if (!element.classList.contains('active')) { // had to fix this as variable classList wasn't defined
        element.classList.add('active');
    }
    else {
        element.classList.remove('active');
    }
}
```

Also, as @Teemu suggested in comments, but refused to write it, feel free to use `element.classList.toggle('active');`.
So the whole code should be:

```
function changeClass(element) {
    element = document.getElementsByClassName(element)[0]; // assuming here we're selecting the first one
    element.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) between two classes, you can do something like this:

```
function changeClass(element) {
    element.classList.toggle('Content');
}
```

Though in this case you've to pass a reference to the element rather than it's className.

Comment: Funny how you got +1 without addressing the actual error.

Comment: @Shomz I thought it was your upvote : ). Actually there was also an error in my answer (at least when comparing to OP's code).

Comment: Haha, no, you didn't have an answer posted when I posted mine, that's why I mentioned you in mine. Yeah, I think we've got it all covered now. Here's one from me now.

Comment: @Shomz I think so, though after reading the question again, I guess `Content` is a className OP want's to toggle... +1 for your answer anyway.

Comment: You mean `Content` with capital C? Well, that's up to him to figure out. :)